# Dagger 2 with Android Studio 3.0 Preview (Canary 2) using annotationProcessor instead of android-apt

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-studio-3.0, annotation-processor, android-apt

```
"A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...."
```

Ok, long story short - I decided to give `Android Studio 3.0 Preview (Canary 2)` a shot and I cannot make it work with `Dagger 2` using `annotationProcessor` instead of `android-apt`.

The error message I get is a simple one to digest:

```
Error:(59, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent
```

I've read the docs (nothing fancy there, I guess): https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#annotationProcessor_config

And changed the `build.gradle` file to:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
```

Where `daggerVersion = '2.11'`

Also, I made sure that appropriate options are checked in Android Studio (were not checked by default):

```
File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings -> 
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> 
Enable annotation processors -> IS CHECKED
```

Unfortunately, it does not help.

Gradle:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Android Plugin for Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
    ...
}
```

How do I make it work with `annotationProcessor` instead of `android-apt`?

*EDIT #1*

I've added these "supposed-to-be-extra-ones" dependencies "just in case of"

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

And now I get an error about conflicting scopes... Oo

```
SomeSubComponent has conflicting scopes:
AppComponent also has @Singleton
```

I did upgrade Dagger from `2.6.1` to `2.11`, so now I'm looking for some "breaking changes" in Release Notes: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

*Edit #2*

The good news is that the first "breaking change" was introduced in `2.9` My wild guess is that this is due to "New Validation". The bad news is that, most probably, the problem was already there for ages. https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.9

Reviewing structure of `(Sub)Components` and `Scoped Dependencies`.

*Edit #3*

Currently, this issue is related to this one: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107

Consider the following example:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
    SomeComponent plus(SomeModule someModule);
}

@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Integer provideInteger() {
        return 1;
    }
}

@Singleton
@Subcomponent(modules = {
        SomeModule.class
})
public interface SomeComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}

@Module
public class SomeModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public String provideText(Integer number) {
        return number.toString();
    }
}
```

This is no longer possible with `Dagger 2.9+`. The `Component` has to use a different `Scope` then the `Subcomponent`s. Like this:

```
    @Scope
    public @interface ApplicationScope {
    }

    @Module
    public class AppModule {

        @Provides
        @ApplicationScope
        public Integer provideInteger() {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @ApplicationScope
    @Component(modules = {
            AppModule.class
    })
    public interface AppComponent {
        SomeComponent plus(SomeModule someModule);
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is the error because the dagger is not setup properly

Comment: Is this the only error you are getting? `Error:(59, 24) error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent`

Comment: Yes, the only one I get. Basically, `:app:compileProdDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED`.

Comment: have you made any dagger dependency classes? like components and all?

Comment: We are talking about a successful project that is extensively using Dagger 2 for I-don't-even-remember-how-long™ ;)

Comment: yes what I am guessing is you must have created some wrong class somewhere in the project thus your app is not compiling

Comment: Well, I did upgrade Dagger 2 from `2.6.1` to `2.11`... Trying to spot a "breaking change" here: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Comment: Are you using kotlin-android plugin?

Answer (score -3):

1. Don't be a "smartass" and stick to what the docs say:

   ```
   implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
   annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
   ```
2. When migrating to `Dagger 2.9+` use different `(Custom)Scope`s for `Component`s and `Subcomponent`s "singletons".

See the Question's description for more verbose explanation.

Also, I think that the Release Notes for `2.9` could be more explicit about this change, no? :/
https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.9